# Arrays with PHP wont evaluate

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `config.php` file which has some constants and methods.
I have a `test.php` file which calls one of the methods in `config.php`.
The relevant code is:

```
$Questions = array(
    1 => "Is he/she nice?1",
    2 => "Is he/she sweet?2",
    3 => "Is he/she nice?3",
    4 => "Is he/she sweet?4",
    5 => "Is he/she nice?5",
    6 => "Is he/she sweet?6",
    7 => "Is he/she nice?7",
    8 => "Is he/she sweet?8",
    9 => "Is he/she nice?9",
    10 => "Is he/she sweet?10"
);


function PrintAnswersOnMe($uid)
{
    $uid = antiSQLi($uid);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM AnsAns WHERE fid='".$uid."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rrr = $row[2];
        echo $Questions[1];
        echo $rrr . ' ' . $Questions[$rrr];
        echo "You'r friend <img src='http://graph.facebook.com/".$row['uid']."/picture/' /> answered " . (($row['answer'] == 1) ? "yes" : "no") . " about wether you're ". $rrr.": " . $Questions[$rrr];
        echo "<br /> " . $Questions['2'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

The `test` file only calls `PrintAnswersOnMe`. (it includes it)
Everything works file, excpet that *no* `$Question[...]` evaluates to actual HTML output!
To check that, I've added `$Questions[2]` - and also `$Questions['2']` - and none of them produce HTML output. The loop does execute because everything else is getting to the HTML.
The funny thing is that inside `test.php` it does works - `echo $Questions[...]` is actually products to HTML output. Does anyone have any idea about this mysterious behavior?

Comment: Where are you defining $Questions?  In the file you include, or the calling script?  If it's defined in the include, I believe it's out of the scope of when you call PrintAnswersOnMe()

Comment: The variable is outside the scope of the function. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for further reading

Comment: Dude, get some _basic_ PHP knowledge, please. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `global $Questions;` to the beginning of your function, before `$uid = antiSQLi($uid);`.

Comment: noooooooooo :-) global bad; just parse it as an argument to the function

Comment: Why is a global bad? It's already a global, so there's no harm in fixing it to make it work properly. It doesn't seem like it's going to change on each invocation, so it doesn't really need to be an argument

Comment: I believe this is the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
function PrintAnswersOnMe($uid, $questions) {
//Code goes here
}
```

Then you'll have access

Comment: This requires calls to `PrintAnswersOnMe` to add it as a parameter, as well.